# Delete a full function in VIM

Tags: c++, c, vim, command, vi

Is there a way of deleting a full (C, C++) function in VIM using a single command?

Let's suppose I have the following function:

```
void foo(int arg1, int arg2) {
    // do some stuff
    myfunction(arg1);

    // do other stuff separated by blank line for readability
    myotherfunction(arg2);
}
```

Using the command `di{` just takes what's inside the brackets, without deleting the function definition.
Using the command `dip` doesn't work because the blank line inside the function creates a new paragraph.

Of course I can always do a `di{` followed by `dd` to delete the function definition, but is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can mark the content that has to be deleted using <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> command, and then press <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>'</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> to delete it.

---

Suppose you want to delete the whole function, then take the cursor to the beginning of the function

```
void foo(int arg1, int arg2) {
```

press <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>, move the cursor down till the line you want to delete.

```
}
```

and then press <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>'</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>